# Angular 5 with Angular Material - Button Ripple Effect not working

Tags: angular5, angular-material2

I have tried to apply the normal button of angular material but the ripple affect will not work at all.

Iv'e got:

```
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'hammerjs';
import 'web-animations-js';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';

imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [WeatherService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, WeatherComponentComponent]
})
```

In the global styles.css file i have: @import

```
'~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
dependancies:
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.10",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"

  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/node": "^9.6.6",
    "codelyzer": "^4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "protractor": "^5.3.1",
    "ts-node": "^6.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.0"
  }
```

HTML:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary">Button</button>
```

I have also tried to link the stylesheet in the global HTML - but doesn't work still.

Comment: you still need to define a theme. Have you included a Material theme?

Comment: Of course, I have added this theme in the global css: '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';

Comment: any reason you are bootstrapping `WeatherComponentComponent`? Normally you'd only bootstrap one entry component. Try moving `WeatherComponentComponent` to `declarations` instead of `bootstrap`. I'm guessing it's not getting the module imports for that reason

Comment: Okay I think I may have found some bug in angular as I was able to track the cause. It was due to usage of variable inside here:        <div *ngIf="shown;else other_content"> 
           {{forecasts.list[0].dt}}
        </div>
        <ng-template #other_content>
        
                <span>Temperature (celsius): {{ weathers.main.temp }} </span>

              
        </ng-template> . - So basically using  {{ weathers.main.temp }}  within that broke the animations in the entire page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay I think I may have found some bug in angular as I was able to track the cause. It was due to usage of variable inside here:  {{forecasts.list[0].dt}}   Temperature (celsius): {{ weathers.main.temp }}   . - So basically using {{ weathers.main.temp }} within that broke the animations in the entire page. –

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem and I solved the issue at the end. 
I looked at several SO posts but none of them works in my case. 
I'll show how I did below, so it might help anyone who came across the issue.

## Context

I was working on the [Tutorial: Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) in Angular's site, so my app was fairly small and simple. To use the material components, I follow the "Getting Started" page on the [Angular Material official website](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started). I use Angular CLI, so I imported the prebuilt theme css in `styles.css`, imported MatButtonModule and tried `<button mat-button>basic</button>`, but the button ripple effect just didn't work.

## Solution

In `index.html` add a class `mat-app-background` to body like this

```
<body class="mat-app-background">
...
</body>
```

And the ripple effect in button is now working!

## Explanation Please

This solution is based on [Angular Material Theming Guide](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md). They have a few words about additional settings before the theming actually works:

> Finally, if your app's content is not placed inside of a `mat-sidenav-container` element, you need to add the `mat-app-background` class to your wrapper element (for example the `body`). This ensures that the proper theme background is applied to your page.

This isn't mentioned in [Angular Material's Getting Started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) page. So if you follow that page and test the `mat-button` right away, it might not work.

## Does that work for everyone?

Definitely not. The solution above is more likely to work if your situation is similar to mine. But I will show you what step I did before, which leads to my situation.

I use Angular CLI to create my Angular app, and I followed the [Getting Started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) tutorial as below:

1. I installed these packages: `@angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations`
2. I Imported `MatButtonModule` in `app.module.ts`.

In `app.module.ts` I have

```
...
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...
    MatButtonModule, // import the Angular Material modules after Angular's BrowserModule, as described in the tutorial.
  ],
  ...
})
```

3. Import prebuilt theming CSS

In `styles.css`

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css';
...
```

4. Now add the button in HTML

In `app.component.html`

```
...
<button mat-button>Basic</button>
...
```

And I clicked on the button and ripple effect did not work. So I got stuck here. But, a strange thing is, if I switch to the prebuilt theme `deeppurple-amber.css`, the ripple then works, without applying the **Solution** above.

If I switch to other prebuilt themes like `purple-green.css` or `pink-bluegrey.css`, ripple effect is again not working. I'm not sure what the cause is, but probably the theming is still not configured properly so things become unpredictable. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, which is not a good sign, so let's proceed to the next step.

5. If your ripple effect did not work so far like me, follow the information in **Solution** and the instructions in [Theming Guide](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md). According to the theming guide, you either need the element `mat-sidenav-container` or the class `mat-app-background` to make material theming configured properly. Then finally, the ripple effect should work now.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution for OP, but this is what's been causing it for me:

**Make sure the `BrowserAnimationsModule` is imported:**

```js
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

---

*The project I'm working on had the `NoopAnimationsModule` included, remove this first; you can't add them both.*

Answer (score 2):

For me it was an **easy mistake to make** if you skim the documentation. This was my problem...

**This**:
`@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css';`

**Was here**:
The **Component** or **Module** `.scss` files...

**But needed to be here**:
The `styles.scss` file found in the `/app` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When, I created buttons using material, the ripple effect was not happening. Later, I found that I did not include any style-theme in the project. So, it's a very basic but most essential thing to check when you are going to start a project in Angular-Material to include at least its pre-built theme style sheet. Then, you are not going to miss the ripple effect. This was my solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `MatRippleModule` imported into the module of that component